# object HTMLTextAreaElement javascript response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, textarea

Why can't I get the content in a tinymce textarea through Javascript/Jquery? With all the things I've tried, it has always given me `[object HTMLTextAreaElement]` As a response. What am I doing wrong?

Javascript:

```
function changeText2(){
  var content =  tinyMCE.getContent('content');
}

alert(content);
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="content" onkeyup='changeText2()' name="page" cols="50" rows="15">
    tinymce editable content in here
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting the textarea element itself. To get its value, add `.value`.

Comment: Now can you tell me why the variable content is changing when I type in the text area?

Answer (score 0):

Obtain active element:

```
var focused = document.activeElement;
focused = WhoFocusseth(focused);

function WhoFocusseth(focused){

    if(!focused || focused == document.body){

        focused = null;

        return focused;

    } else if(document.querySelector){

        focused = document.querySelector(":focus");

        return focused;

    }

}
```

Now you can get the element id :

```
var Which_Elem_In_Focus = focused.id;
```

Pure Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add .value

> alert(content.value);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).